# Javascript function available in another Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap modal in my project and I have the following scenario.
I have one html page **Index.html** which contains code to open bootstrap modal on button click using following code.

```
jQuery('#modellink').click(function(e) {
  $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
  });
});
```

In the load method **URL** load dynamically. The issue is that when I load **modalbox.html** into bootstrap modal which contains **test()** javascript function. After that when I again load another HTML file 
**modalbox1.html** which does not contain any javascript function. Even if **modalbox1.html** does not contain any javascript function then also **test()** javascript function is available since **modalbox.html** opened previously. So please help me how can I resolved this issue.

Comment: what is triggering the `test` method

Comment: test contains empty body.below is my test function. function test(){
 
 }.The test() function available when I load another html in modal.

Comment: please try to add working snippet

Comment: I have separate project to create above scenario. Where to upload?Please let me know.

Comment: Scripts in dynamic content are tricky because they may or may not work exactly as you expect.  I normally try to put them in the main view instead of the AJAX code, or in a script file that gets loaded along with the AJAX call.

Comment: I put it in separate script file and get loaded along with ajax call then also not working.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding based on your explanation, you do not want the function test() to be available for another HTML file loaded with AJAX correct?

This can be easily accomplished by declaring the function in a different closure ([How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1))

In other words, to enclose it within another function, like

```
(function() {
    //test is declared within the scope of the outer function only so it will not be available in the global closure, i.e. available to other HTML loaded after this
    function test() {
        //do something here
    }
    document.getElementById("someButton").addEventListener("click", test);
})();
```